# Why do I need to `require` a module that is already compiled and loaded?

Tags: elixir

According to `h require` in `iex`, `require` "Requires a given module to be compiled and loaded", and is needed "if you want to use the macros from a module".

Yet it seems that even if a module **is** compiled and loaded, I still need to call `require` to call its macros. For example:

```
# "require" the file in the sense of "go compile it right now"
# Without doing this (or something equivilent, like `elixir -r macro_module.ex`),
# a call to `require MacroModule` will fail with CompileError: "module MacroModule
# is not loaded and could not be found"
Code.require_file("path/to/macro_module.ex")

defmodule MyModule1 do
  require MacroModule
  MacroModule.some_macro # works
end

defmodule MyModule2 do
  # fails with CompileError: "you must require MacroModule before invoking the
  # macro MacroModule.some_macro/0"
  MacroModule.some_macro
end
```

Why do I need to `require MacroModule` inside `MyModule2` when its successful usage in `MyModule1` clearly shows that it has been compiled and loaded?

(I see that the docs say `require` is lexically-scoped, but I don't really understand that in this case, since I'm using a global reference like `MacroModule.some_macro` and not a local one like `import MacroModule; some_macro`.)

Comment: I'm using Elixir 1.2.1

Comment: I also don't understand the "is not loaded **and could not be found**" message. Where did it look before it said "could not be found"? `require` does not go and search the files in a load path, as it does in Ruby.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This page](http://elixir-lang.readthedocs.org/en/latest/technical/scoping.html#require-import-and-alias) explains the scoping rules for *require*.  Basically the require statement is only valid within the scope of the do block in which it's invoked.  Hence it'd be like this:

```
defmodule MyModule1 do
  require MacroModule #require now in scope
  MacroModule.some_macro 
end #require goes out of scope
```

Comment: Yep, as I said, `require` is lexically-scoped. The confusing thing for me is that `MacroModule.some_macro`, which doesn't *look* like a local reference, is still only available in scopes that have called `require MyMacro`. But that's just the way it is, I guess. :)

Comment: May have something to do with macro hygiene but that's simply a guess on my part.  I mean it may have something to do with keeping macros from bleeding over into other modules.